# symfony4 use .env config variables in a service

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I am using a package that is not especially made for symfony (TNTsearch), and have put all the functions I want to use in a service I called `TNTsearchHelper.php`. This service requires some variables, including some that could be found in the `.env` file. I currently define and construct these in my class:

```
class TntSearchHelper
{
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;

        $config = [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'databasename',
            'username'  => 'user',
            'password'  => 'pw',
            'storage'   => 'my/path/to/file',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        ];

        $this->config = $config;
    }
```

What I would really like is to simply use the variables for my database that are set in the `.env` file. Is there any way to do this? This service is not registered in `services.yaml` because this is not neccesary with the `autowire: true` option, so I don't have any config options/file for my service in the `config` and wonder if I can keep it that way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. It's possible. If you want to use env variables for configuration, you have two options:

1.Use `getenv`:

```
$config = [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => getenv('MYSQL_HOST'),
    'database'  => getenv('MYSQL_DB'),
    'username'  => getenv('MYSQL_LOGIN'),
    'password'  => getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD'),
    'storage'   => 'my/path/to/file',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
];
```

2.Configure your service in `services.yaml`:

```
services:
  App\TntSearchHelper:
    arguments:
      - '%env(MYSQL_HOST)%'
      - '%env(MYSQL_DB)%'
      - '%env(MYSQL_LOGIN)%'
      - '%env(MYSQL_PASSWORD)%'
```

And change your `__construct` function to this:

```
public function __construct(string $host, string $db, string $login, string $password, EntityManagerInterface $em) 
{
    $this->em = $em;
    $config = [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => $host,
        'database'  => $db,
        'username'  => $login,
        'password'  => $password,
        'storage'   => 'my/path/to/file',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    ];
    $this->config = $config;
}
```

Also make sure that all this env variables are set because there's only `DATABASE_URL` variable in `.env` file by default

Comment: I must add a reminder, because the getenv returns on some servers always false, I looked further and getenv() is not ideal solution, because: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63814025/1376033

Answer (score 3):

I know three possibilities. Each case has 03 steps configuration : 
1 - declare yours variables in env. 
2 - config service file 
3 - and call your parameter

_ In controllers extending from the **AbstractController**, and use the getParameter() helper :

**YAML file config**

```
# config/services.yaml
parameters:
    kernel.project_dir: "%env(variable_name)%"
    app.admin_email: "%env(variable_name)%"
```

**In your service,**

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    // ...

    public function index(): Response
    {
        $projectDir = $this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir');
        $adminEmail = $this->getParameter('app.admin_email');

        // ...
    }
}
```

_ In services and controllers not extending from **AbstractController**, inject the parameters as arguments of their constructors.

**YAML file config**

```
# config/services.yaml
parameters:
    app.contents_dir: "%env(variable_name)%"

services:
    App\Service\MessageGenerator:
        arguments:
            $contentsDir: '%app.contents_dir%'
```

**In your service,**

```
class MessageGenerator
{
    private $params;

    public function __construct(string $contentsDir)
    {
        $this->params = $contentsDir;
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        $parameterValue = $this->params;
        // ...
    }
}
```

_ Finally, if some service needs access to lots of parameters, instead of injecting each of them individually, you can inject all the application parameters at once by type-hinting any of its constructor arguments with the ContainerBagInterface:

**YAML file config**

```
# config/services.yaml
parameters:
    app.parameter_name: "%env(variable_name)%"
```

**In your service,**

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ContainerBagInterface;

class MessageGenerator
{
    private $params;

    public function __construct(ContainerBagInterface $params)
    {
        $this->params = $params;
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        $parameterValue = $this->params->get('app.parameter_name');
        // ...
    }
}
```

*source* [Accessing Configuration Parameters](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#accessing-configuration-parameters)